# Able to Hide TreeView menu for login page, but horizontal "slit" still appears

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview menu as part of a series of aspx pages. On all of the pages I want the treeview menu to show except for the login page.

I have accomplished making the treeview menu to not show on the login page by using

TreeView1.Visible = false;

in my Frontend.master.cs page under Page_Load.

My question has to do with the fact that now when I load the login.aspx page a "tiny horizonal slit" appears where the menu "begins" at the top left side of the page. This seems to be a type of "container" that is showing empty, but after reading and looking I am unable to completely delete and trace of the treeView menu on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your `TreeView` inside of a `Panel`, and hide that instead. It gives more flexibility on hiding other things as well.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <p>A description I want to hide as well.</p>
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
    </asp:TreeView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then hide this with

```
this.Master.Panel1.Visible = false;
```